# import User Profile SQL Database to Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, sql, azure

Im a beginner that is thrying to setup my first website in Windows Azure. I have published it and made a Sql database inside Windows Azure.

In my local virtual machine I have SQL management studio that contain a User profile database. Is there a way to export that one and import to Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy it directly from SSMS. Right click a database in the Object Explorer pane select Tasks - > Deploy database to Windows Azure SQL Database command:

[image]

In the Deployment Settings click the Connect button, and connect to your Azure Server:

[image]

Click Next:

[image]

Review summary, and click Finish:

[image]

After successful deployment connect to your Azure Server in SSMS and you'll see your database:

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you encountered an error during the deployment check the list of limitations in Azure SQL Database:

[Azure SQL Database General Guidelines and Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336245.aspx)

[Azure SQL Database Security Guidelines and Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394108.aspx)

[SQL Server Feature Limitations (Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394115.aspx)

Also, here is a blog post on how to use SQL Server Data tools to migrate a database to SQL Azure: [Migrating a Database to SQL Azure using SSDT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/04/19/migrating-a-database-to-sql-azure-using-ssdt.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Now I get the exact same problem as this guy: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/ebed574c-2479-45f1-aab1-8809ca7d80e6/textinrowsize-set-error-in-deploy-to-azure?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: Please see the update, there are features in SQL Server that are not supported in Windows SQL Azure, i also added a link on how you can use SSDT to change your database for migration